# How can I connect my ESP32-WROOM-32 to Arduino IDE?

Tags: arduino-ide, esp32

I'm using this 'ESP32-WROOM-32' but I can't find the correct board in the IDE. I see the esp32-wroom-DA (edit, i took it to the store where i bought it and it worked fine with theirs. they were on windows and im on mac. also they told me to use 'DOIT esp32 devkit' but im getting the same errors) but when I use that with this board it gives errors while compiling.

> Arduino: 1.8.18 (Mac OS X), Board: "ESP32-WROOM-DA Module, Default 4MB with spiffs (1.2MB APP/1.5MB SPIFFS), 240MHz (WiFi/BT), QIO, 80MHz, 4MB (32Mb), 921600, Core 1, Core 1, None, Disabled"
> [2074] Error loading Python lib '/var/folders/sz/zm5vw9m92t9_07j6scr85q400000gn/T/_MEIDMFx0d/libpython3.8.dylib': dlopen: dlopen(/var/folders/sz/zm5vw9m92t9_07j6scr85q400000gn/T/_MEIDMFx0d/libpython3.8.dylib, 10): Library not loaded: @loader_path/libintl.8.dylib
> Referenced from: /var/folders/sz/zm5vw9m92t9_07j6scr85q400000gn/T/_MEIDMFx0d/libpython3.8.dylib
> Reason: no suitable image found. Did find:
>     >/var/folders/sz/zm5vw9m92t9_07j6scr85q400000gn/T/_MEIDMFx0d/libintl.8.dylib: cannot load 'libintl.8.dylib' (load command 0x80000034 is unknown)
> /private/var/folders/sz/zm5vw9m92t9_07j6scr85q400000gn/T/_MEIDMFx0d/libintl.8.dylib: cannot load 'libintl.8.dylib' (load command 0x80000034 is unknown)
> exit status 255
> /private/var/folders/sz/zm5vw9m92t9_07j6scr85q400000gn/T/AppTranslocation/F61C5E6A-0B57-4967-97C2-77C38540CF2B/d/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/arduino-builder returned 255
> Error compiling for board ESP32-WROOM-DA Module.
>
> This report would have more information with
> "Show verbose output during compilation"
> option enabled in File -> Preferences.

And when I enabled show verbose output:

> Arduino: 1.8.18 (Mac OS X), Board: "ESP32-WROOM-DA Module, Default 4MB with spiffs (1.2MB APP/1.5MB SPIFFS), 240MHz (WiFi/BT), QIO, 80MHz, 4MB (32Mb), 921600, Core 1, Core 1, None, Disabled"
>
> /private/var/folders/sz/zm5vw9m92t9_07j6scr85q400000gn/T/AppTranslocation/F61C5E6A-0B57-4967-97C2-77C38540CF2B/d/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/arduino-builder -dump-prefs -logger=machine -hardware /private/var/folders/sz/zm5vw9m92t9_07j6scr85q400000gn/T/AppTranslocation/F61C5E6A-0B57-4967-97C2-77C38540CF2B/d/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware -hardware /Users/drayeshahakim/Library/Arduino15/packages -tools /private/var/folders/sz/zm5vw9m92t9_07j6scr85q400000gn/T/AppTranslocation/F61C5E6A-0B57-4967-97C2-77C38540CF2B/d/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/tools-builder -tools /private/var/folders/sz/zm5vw9m92t9_07j6scr85q400000gn/T/AppTranslocation/F61C5E6A-0B57-4967-97C2-77C38540CF2B/d/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr -tools /Users/drayeshahakim/Library/Arduino15/packages -built-in-libraries /private/var/folders/sz/zm5vw9m92t9_07j6scr85q400000gn/T/AppTranslocation/F61C5E6A-0B57-4967-97C2-77C38540CF2B/d/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/libraries -libraries /Users/drayeshahakim/Documents/Arduino/libraries -fqbn=esp32:esp32:esp32da:PartitionScheme=default,CPUFreq=240,FlashMode=qio,FlashFreq=80,FlashSize=4M,UploadSpeed=921600,LoopCore=1,EventsCore=1,DebugLevel=none,EraseFlash=none -vid-pid=0000_0000 -ide-version=10818 -build-path /var/folders/sz/zm5vw9m92t9_07j6scr85q400000gn/T/arduino_build_386453 -warnings=none -build-cache /var/folders/sz/zm5vw9m92t9_07j6scr85q400000gn/T/arduino_cache_107457 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.esptool_py.path=/Users/drayeshahakim/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/tools/esptool_py/4.5.1 -prefs=runtime.tools.esptool_py-4.5.1.path=/Users/drayeshahakim/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/tools/esptool_py/4.5.1 -prefs=runtime.tools.xtensa-esp32s2-elf-gcc.path=/Users/drayeshahakim/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/tools/xtensa-esp32s2-elf-gcc/esp-2021r2-patch5-8.4.0 -prefs=runtime.tools.xtensa-esp32s2-elf-gcc-esp-2021r2-patch5-8.4.0.path=/Users/drayeshahakim/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/tools/xtensa-esp32s2-elf-gcc/esp-2021r2-patch5-8.4.0 -prefs=runtime.tools.mklittlefs.path=/Users/drayeshahakim/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/tools/mklittlefs/3.0.0-gnu12-dc7f933 -prefs=runtime.tools.mklittlefs-3.0.0-gnu12-dc7f933.path=/Users/drayeshahakim/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/tools/mklittlefs/3.0.0-gnu12-dc7f933 -prefs=runtime.tools.xtensa-esp32s3-elf-gcc.path=/Users/drayeshahakim/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/tools/xtensa-esp32s3-elf-gcc/esp-2021r2-patch5-8.4.0 -prefs=runtime.tools.xtensa-esp32s3-elf-gcc-esp-2021r2-patch5-8.4.0.path=/Users/drayeshahakim/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/tools/xtensa-esp32s3-elf-gcc/esp-2021r2-patch5-8.4.0 -prefs=runtime.tools.xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc.path=/Users/drayeshahakim/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc/esp-2021r2-patch5-8.4.0 -prefs=runtime.tools.xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc-esp-2021r2-patch5-8.4.0.path=/Users/drayeshahakim/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc/esp-2021r2-patch5-8.4.0 -prefs=runtime.tools.riscv32-esp-elf-gcc.path=/Users/drayeshahakim/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/tools/riscv32-esp-elf-gcc/esp-2021r2-patch5-8.4.0 -prefs=runtime.tools.riscv32-esp-elf-gcc-esp-2021r2-patch5-8.4.0.path=/Users/drayeshahakim/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/tools/riscv32-esp-elf-gcc/esp-2021r2-patch5-8.4.0 -prefs=runtime.tools.dfu-util.path=/Users/drayeshahakim/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/dfu-util/0.11.0-arduino5 -prefs=runtime.tools.dfu-util-0.11.0-arduino5.path=/Users/drayeshahakim/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/dfu-util/0.11.0-arduino5 -prefs=runtime.tools.riscv32-esp-elf-gdb.path=/Users/drayeshahakim/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/tools/riscv32-esp-elf-gdb/11.2_20220823 -prefs=runtime.tools.riscv32-esp-elf-gdb-11.2_20220823.path=/Users/drayeshahakim/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/tools/riscv32-esp-elf-gdb/11.2_20220823 -prefs=runtime.tools.openocd-esp32.path=/Users/drayeshahakim/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/tools/openocd-esp32/v0.11.0-esp32-20221026 -prefs=runtime.tools.openocd-esp32-v0.11.0-esp32-20221026.path=/Users/drayeshahakim/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/tools/openocd-esp32/v0.11.0-esp32-20221026 -prefs=runtime.tools.xtensa-esp-elf-gdb.path=/Users/drayeshahakim/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/tools/xtensa-esp-elf-gdb/11.2_20220823 -prefs=runtime.tools.xtensa-esp-elf-gdb-11.2_20220823.path=/Users/drayeshahakim/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/tools/xtensa-esp-elf-gdb/11.2_20220823 -prefs=runtime.tools.mkspiffs.path=/Users/drayeshahakim/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/tools/mkspiffs/0.2.3 -prefs=runtime.tools.mkspiffs-0.2.3.path=/Users/drayeshahakim/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/tools/mkspiffs/0.2.3 -verbose /private/var/folders/sz/zm5vw9m92t9_07j6scr85q400000gn/T/AppTranslocation/F61C5E6A-0B57-4967-97C2-77C38540CF2B/d/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/examples/01.Basics/Blink/Blink.ino
> /private/var/folders/sz/zm5vw9m92t9_07j6scr85q400000gn/T/AppTranslocation/F61C5E6A-0B57-4967-97C2-77C38540CF2B/d/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/arduino-builder -compile -logger=machine -hardware /private/var/folders/sz/zm5vw9m92t9_07j6scr85q400000gn/T/AppTranslocation/F61C5E6A-0B57-4967-97C2-77C38540CF2B/d/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware -hardware /Users/drayeshahakim/Library/Arduino15/packages -tools /private/var/folders/sz/zm5vw9m92t9_07j6scr85q400000gn/T/AppTranslocation/F61C5E6A-0B57-4967-97C2-77C38540CF2B/d/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/tools-builder -tools /private/var/folders/sz/zm5vw9m92t9_07j6scr85q400000gn/T/AppTranslocation/F61C5E6A-0B57-4967-97C2-77C38540CF2B/d/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr -tools /Users/drayeshahakim/Library/Arduino15/packages -built-in-libraries /private/var/folders/sz/zm5vw9m92t9_07j6scr85q400000gn/T/AppTranslocation/F61C5E6A-0B57-4967-97C2-77C38540CF2B/d/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/libraries -libraries /Users/drayeshahakim/Documents/Arduino/libraries -fqbn=esp32:esp32:esp32da:PartitionScheme=default,CPUFreq=240,FlashMode=qio,FlashFreq=80,FlashSize=4M,UploadSpeed=921600,LoopCore=1,EventsCore=1,DebugLevel=none,EraseFlash=none -vid-pid=0000_0000 -ide-version=10818 -build-path /var/folders/sz/zm5vw9m92t9_07j6scr85q400000gn/T/arduino_build_386453 -warnings=none -build-cache /var/folders/sz/zm5vw9m92t9_07j6scr85q400000gn/T/arduino_cache_107457 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.esptool_py.path=/Users/drayeshahakim/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/tools/esptool_py/4.5.1 -prefs=runtime.tools.esptool_py-4.5.1.path=/Users/drayeshahakim/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/tools/esptool_py/4.5.1 -prefs=runtime.tools.xtensa-esp32s2-elf-gcc.path=/Users/drayeshahakim/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/tools/xtensa-esp32s2-elf-gcc/esp-2021r2-patch5-8.4.0 -prefs=runtime.tools.xtensa-esp32s2-elf-gcc-esp-2021r2-patch5-8.4.0.path=/Users/drayeshahakim/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/tools/xtensa-esp32s2-elf-gcc/esp-2021r2-patch5-8.4.0 -prefs=runtime.tools.mklittlefs.path=/Users/drayeshahakim/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/tools/mklittlefs/3.0.0-gnu12-dc7f933 -prefs=runtime.tools.mklittlefs-3.0.0-gnu12-dc7f933.path=/Users/drayeshahakim/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/tools/mklittlefs/3.0.0-gnu12-dc7f933 -prefs=runtime.tools.xtensa-esp32s3-elf-gcc.path=/Users/drayeshahakim/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/tools/xtensa-esp32s3-elf-gcc/esp-2021r2-patch5-8.4.0 -prefs=runtime.tools.xtensa-esp32s3-elf-gcc-esp-2021r2-patch5-8.4.0.path=/Users/drayeshahakim/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/tools/xtensa-esp32s3-elf-gcc/esp-2021r2-patch5-8.4.0 -prefs=runtime.tools.xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc.path=/Users/drayeshahakim/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc/esp-2021r2-patch5-8.4.0 -prefs=runtime.tools.xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc-esp-2021r2-patch5-8.4.0.path=/Users/drayeshahakim/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc/esp-2021r2-patch5-8.4.0 -prefs=runtime.tools.riscv32-esp-elf-gcc.path=/Users/drayeshahakim/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/tools/riscv32-esp-elf-gcc/esp-2021r2-patch5-8.4.0 -prefs=runtime.tools.riscv32-esp-elf-gcc-esp-2021r2-patch5-8.4.0.path=/Users/drayeshahakim/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/tools/riscv32-esp-elf-gcc/esp-2021r2-patch5-8.4.0 -prefs=runtime.tools.dfu-util.path=/Users/drayeshahakim/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/dfu-util/0.11.0-arduino5 -prefs=runtime.tools.dfu-util-0.11.0-arduino5.path=/Users/drayeshahakim/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/dfu-util/0.11.0-arduino5 -prefs=runtime.tools.riscv32-esp-elf-gdb.path=/Users/drayeshahakim/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/tools/riscv32-esp-elf-gdb/11.2_20220823 -prefs=runtime.tools.riscv32-esp-elf-gdb-11.2_20220823.path=/Users/drayeshahakim/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/tools/riscv32-esp-elf-gdb/11.2_20220823 -prefs=runtime.tools.openocd-esp32.path=/Users/drayeshahakim/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/tools/openocd-esp32/v0.11.0-esp32-20221026 -prefs=runtime.tools.openocd-esp32-v0.11.0-esp32-20221026.path=/Users/drayeshahakim/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/tools/openocd-esp32/v0.11.0-esp32-20221026 -prefs=runtime.tools.xtensa-esp-elf-gdb.path=/Users/drayeshahakim/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/tools/xtensa-esp-elf-gdb/11.2_20220823 -prefs=runtime.tools.xtensa-esp-elf-gdb-11.2_20220823.path=/Users/drayeshahakim/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/tools/xtensa-esp-elf-gdb/11.2_20220823 -prefs=runtime.tools.mkspiffs.path=/Users/drayeshahakim/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/tools/mkspiffs/0.2.3 -prefs=runtime.tools.mkspiffs-0.2.3.path=/Users/drayeshahakim/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/tools/mkspiffs/0.2.3 -verbose /private/var/folders/sz/zm5vw9m92t9_07j6scr85q400000gn/T/AppTranslocation/F61C5E6A-0B57-4967-97C2-77C38540CF2B/d/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/examples/01.Basics/Blink/Blink.ino
> Using board 'esp32da' from platform in folder: /Users/drayeshahakim/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/hardware/esp32/2.0.11
> Using core 'esp32' from platform in folder: /Users/drayeshahakim/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/hardware/esp32/2.0.11
> bash -c "[ ! -f "/private/var/folders/sz/zm5vw9m92t9_07j6scr85q400000gn/T/AppTranslocation/F61C5E6A-0B57-4967-97C2-77C38540CF2B/d/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/examples/01.Basics/Blink"/partitions.csv ] || cp -f "/private/var/folders/sz/zm5vw9m92t9_07j6scr85q400000gn/T/AppTranslocation/F61C5E6A-0B57-4967-97C2-77C38540CF2B/d/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/examples/01.Basics/Blink"/partitions.csv "/var/folders/sz/zm5vw9m92t9_07j6scr85q400000gn/T/arduino_build_386453"/partitions.csv"
> bash -c "[ -f "/var/folders/sz/zm5vw9m92t9_07j6scr85q400000gn/T/arduino_build_386453"/partitions.csv ] || [ ! -f "/Users/drayeshahakim/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/hardware/esp32/2.0.11/variants/esp32da"/partitions.csv ] || cp "/Users/drayeshahakim/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/hardware/esp32/2.0.11/variants/esp32da"/partitions.csv "/var/folders/sz/zm5vw9m92t9_07j6scr85q400000gn/T/arduino_build_386453"/partitions.csv"
> bash -c "[ -f "/var/folders/sz/zm5vw9m92t9_07j6scr85q400000gn/T/arduino_build_386453"/partitions.csv ] || cp "/Users/drayeshahakim/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/hardware/esp32/2.0.11"/tools/partitions/default.csv "/var/folders/sz/zm5vw9m92t9_07j6scr85q400000gn/T/arduino_build_386453"/partitions.csv"
> bash -c "[ -f "/private/var/folders/sz/zm5vw9m92t9_07j6scr85q400000gn/T/AppTranslocation/F61C5E6A-0B57-4967-97C2-77C38540CF2B/d/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/examples/01.Basics/Blink"/bootloader.bin ] && cp -f "/private/var/folders/sz/zm5vw9m92t9_07j6scr85q400000gn/T/AppTranslocation/F61C5E6A-0B57-4967-97C2-77C38540CF2B/d/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/examples/01.Basics/Blink"/bootloader.bin "/var/folders/sz/zm5vw9m92t9_07j6scr85q400000gn/T/arduino_build_386453"/Blink.ino.bootloader.bin || ( [ -f "/Users/drayeshahakim/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/hardware/esp32/2.0.11/variants/esp32da"/bootloader.bin ] && cp "/Users/drayeshahakim/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/hardware/esp32/2.0.11/variants/esp32da"/bootloader.bin "/var/folders/sz/zm5vw9m92t9_07j6scr85q400000gn/T/arduino_build_386453"/Blink.ino.bootloader.bin || "/Users/drayeshahakim/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/tools/esptool_py/4.5.1"/esptool --chip esp32 elf2image --flash_mode dio --flash_freq 80m --flash_size 4MB -o "/var/folders/sz/zm5vw9m92t9_07j6scr85q400000gn/T/arduino_build_386453"/Blink.ino.bootloader.bin "/Users/drayeshahakim/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/hardware/esp32/2.0.11/tools/sdk/esp32"/bin/bootloader_qio_80m.elf )"
> [2164] Error loading Python lib '/var/folders/sz/zm5vw9m92t9_07j6scr85q400000gn/T/_MEIXurqHc/libpython3.8.dylib': dlopen: dlopen(/var/folders/sz/zm5vw9m92t9_07j6scr85q400000gn/T/_MEIXurqHc/libpython3.8.dylib, 10): Library not loaded: @loader_path/libintl.8.dylib
> Referenced from: /var/folders/sz/zm5vw9m92t9_07j6scr85q400000gn/T/_MEIXurqHc/libpython3.8.dylib
> Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
> /var/folders/sz/zm5vw9m92t9_07j6scr85q400000gn/T/_MEIXurqHc/libintl.8.dylib: cannot load 'libintl.8.dylib' (load command 0x80000034 is unknown)
> /private/var/folders/sz/zm5vw9m92t9_07j6scr85q400000gn/T/_MEIXurqHc/libintl.8.dylib: cannot load 'libintl.8.dylib' (load command 0x80000034 is unknown)
> exit status 255
> /private/var/folders/sz/zm5vw9m92t9_07j6scr85q400000gn/T/AppTranslocation/F61C5E6A-0B57-4967-97C2-77C38540CF2B/d/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/arduino-builder returned 255
> Error compiling for board ESP32-WROOM-DA Module.

```
also im using macos 10.13.6, the store i got it from (and it worked fine for them) was on windows
```

Comment: what errors? ... please copy all of the error message and paste it into your question ... do not paste a picture ... do not paste into a comment

Comment: What program are you compiling? The blink sketch or one with some special (possibly unsupported) libraries? When you "verify" (compile and link) a program in the Arduino IDE the real hardware does not even need to be connected so there is no possibility for the system to identify a mismatch between the board you select in the IDE and the real board you have in your hand. Only when you attempt to upload the (compiled) program can some rudimentary checks be performed. If the verify fails with the "blink" sketch, suspect an IDE installation problem otherwise suspect your code.

Comment: 6v6gt I get the same error for any code i try to run, even the blink sketch.